# How can we read php function from files

Tags: php

```
$dir = "dir";
foreach ($files as $file){ 

    $filename =  $dir . $files["9"]; 
    $handle = fopen(  $filename , 'r'
}
```

The files I am getting in the loop are php files. So how do I read functions of that class?

Comment: Use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), not `fopen`

Comment: Are you trying to include the PHP in those files into the currently running PHP? If so use `require($filename)`

Comment: I am writing a script to read php files from folder. Then reading the content in the file. But there are some function in that file so i have to check whether some function exist in the file or not.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to be able to use functions and classes from another PHP file, you have to `include` or `require` the file before you use the content of the files.

The difference between these two is, that `require` will through a fatal_compile_error if it was not able to find the file.

You can checkout the manual [here](http://php.net/require).

Example code would be:

```
<?php
require('somefile.php');
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am writing a script to read all files from the folder. And after that i have to read the content in that file. The file is php file content in the file are functions. I have to check whether some function exist in the file or not. Could you help with this problem?

Comment: Just for understanding: Why would you do that?

Comment: Do you think it is possible to read the functions in that file?

Comment: I dont know since I dont understand what you are about to do... .Are you trying to check if the function is working? Do you know what you expect in these files? Whats the background of this task? If you know what is in there you can use try to include them and execute the function with an example and catch any occuring error. However if you do not know these files i strongly recommend not to use any of it.

Comment: It is hard for me to explain why do i need this.  But from that function($parms ) with parameter i call other file in other folder and i params there is some action 
 so i have to check that those action exist in that other file or not. I no its quit difficult for you to undersand but just let me know whether there is any function by which we can read the functions in the file?

Comment: You could include the file and check with function_exists(): http://php.net/manual/de/function.function-exists.php
However if you do not know what is in that file you are probably not the author of the file and i strongly advice not to enclude a executable file you do not know the contents of. Your approach seems pretty messy to me - maybe you should re think what you want to archive and update your question with what you want, what you tried and where the error comes in, since as much as i want to help you - i am basically guessing here ;)